# Can I check which files in my bot are giving me error messages?

Tags: node.js, heroku, twitter

I created a Twitter Bot that posts GIFS every two hours. Recently, I have been getting error messages in heroku log that the file sizes are too large. However, none of my files are over 5MB and my largest file (4.7MB GIF) posted with no problem. Is there a way to check which file is "too large?" Is there another reason I would be getting this error message?

Comment: please post some code used, its hard to say anything by guessing. Also, if there are errors, but it works fine, is there any other log from twitter?

Comment: It works fine. It's just that every so often on the Heroku log it says error over capacity when it tries to upload certain files, it seems.